# Implementation of Double Checked Locking in C++ 98/03 using volatile

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, double-checked-locking

Reading [this](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf) article about Double Checked Locking Pattern in C++, I reached the place (page 10) where the authors demonstrate one of the attempts to implement DCLP "correctly" using `volatile` variables:

```
class Singleton {
public:
  static volatile Singleton* volatile instance();

private:
  static volatile Singleton* volatile pInstance;
};

// from the implementation file
volatile Singleton* volatile Singleton::pInstance = 0;
volatile Singleton* volatile Singleton::instance() {
  if (pInstance == 0) {
    Lock lock;
    if (pInstance == 0) {
      volatile Singleton* volatile temp = new Singleton;
      pInstance = temp;
    }
  }
  return pInstance;
}
```

After such example there is a text snippet that I don't understand:

> First, the Standard’s constraints on observable behavior are only for
>   an abstract machine defined by the Standard, and that abstract machine
>   has no notion of multiple threads of execution. As a result, though
>   the Standard prevents compilers from reordering reads and writes to
>   volatile data *within* a thread, it imposes no constraints at all on
>   such reorderings *across* threads. At least that’s how most compiler
>   implementers interpret things. As a result, in practice, many
>   compilers may generate thread-unsafe code from the source above.

and later:

> ... C++’s abstract machine is single-threaded, and C++ compilers may
>   choose to generate thread-unsafe code from source like the above,
>   anyway.

These remarks are related to the execution on the uni-processor, so it's definitely not about cache-coherence issues.

If the compiler can't reorder reads and writes to volatile data *within* a thread, how can it reorder reads and writes *across* threads for this particular example thus generating thread-unsafe code?

Comment: That article is from 2004, thus predating C++11 and its updated abstract machine by a fair number of years.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok, but how can the statement that compiler can reorder reads and writes _across_ threads be explained?

Answer (score 2):

The pointer to the Singleton may be volatile, but the data *within* the singleton is not.

Imagine Singleton has `int x, y, z;` as members, set to `15, 16, 17` in the constructor for some reason.

```
  volatile Singleton* volatile temp = new Singleton;
  pInstance = temp;
```

OK, `temp` is written before `pInstance`.  When are `x,y,z` written relative to those? Before? After?  You don't know.  They aren't volatile, so they don't need to be ordered relative to the volatile ordering.

Now a thread comes in and sees:

```
if (pInstance == 0) {  // first check
```

And let's say `pInstance` has been set, is not null.
What are the values of `x,y,z`?  Even though `new Singleton` has been called, and the constructor has "run", you don't know whether the operations that set `x,y,z` have run or not.

So now your code goes and reads `x,y,z` and crashes, because it was really expecting `15,16,17`, not random data.

Oh wait, `pInstance` is a volatile pointer to volatile data! So `x,y,z` is volatile right? Right?  And thus ordered with `pInstance` and `temp`. Aha!

Almost.  Any reads from `*pInstance` will be volatile, but the construction via `new Singleton` was not volatile.  So the initial writes to `x,y,z` were not ordered. :-(

So you *could*, *maybe*, make the members `volatile int x, y, z;`  OK.  However...

C++ *now* has a memory model, even if it didn't when the article was written.  Under the current rules, `volatile` does not prevent data races.  `volatile` has nothing to do with threads.  The program is UB. Cats and Dogs living together.

Also, although this is pushing the limits of the standard (ie it gets vague as to what `volatile` really means), an all-knowing, all-seeing, full-program-optimizing compiler could look at your uses of `volatile` and say "no, those volatiles don't actually connect to any IO memory addressses etc, they really aren't observable behaviour, I'm just going to make them non-volatile"...

Comment: I'm sorry, actually, I omitted a part of the article I'm referring to in the question (I believed it would make the question clearer). In that part authors address the problem you're describing. Initialization of the Singleton's fields in the constructor is made in the following way: `static_cast<volatile int&>(x) = 5;` but even after this authors still claim that such solution doesn't solve the problem with the generation of the thread-unsafe code. I know that modern C++ has an elaborated memory model, but it was interesting what did authors mean.

Comment: OK, I've now (re-)read the article (it has been a few years).  I'm tempted to say that the bit you are quoting, and the end of a section leading to the next section, really doesn't have much weight. (Also, for example, cache-coherency isn't usually the problem with multi-processors (since they all (ie all common architectures) ensure cache-coherency), the problem is with the read/write buffers.  So it is a good article, but not necessarily perfect.)  Anyhow, maybe tons of volatile + uniprocessor could actually be thread safe. But `volatile` is poorly defined, so I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think they're referring to the *cache coherency problem* discussed in section 6 ("DCLP on Multiprocessor Machines".  With a multiprocessor system, the processor/cache hardware may write out the value for `pInstance` before the values are written out for the allocated `Singleton`.  This can cause a 2nd CPU to see the non-NULL `pInstance` before it can see the data it points to.

This requires a hardware fence instruction to ensure all the memory is updated before other CPUs in the system can see any of it.

Comment: It doesn't really seem so, because they make a remark at the end of the section 5 suggesting that the multiprocessor execution may introduce even more problems, besides this, section 6 is explicitly named _DCLP on multiprocessor machines_ and in the section 1 _Inroduction_ we can read: "This article explains why Singleton isn’t thread safe, how DCLP attempts to address that problem, why DCLP may fail on **both uni- and multiprocessor** architectures, and why you can’t (portably) do anything about it."

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly they are saying that in the context of a single-thread abstract machine the compiler may simply transform:

```
volatile Singleton* volatile temp = new Singleton;
pInstance = temp;
```

Into:

```
pInstance = new Singleton;
```

Because the observable behavior is unchanged. Then this brings us back to the original problem with double checked locking.

Comment: But I thought that using `volatile`, on the contrary, keeps compilers from making the optimizations you mentioned. According to the C++ 03 Standard 1.9.6: "The observable behavior of the abstract machine is its sequence of reads and writes to `volatile` data and calls to library I/O functions" and 1.9.7: "Accessing an object designated by a
`volatile` lvalue, modifying an object... are all side effects... At certain
specified points ... called sequence points, all side effects of previous  evaluations shall be complete and no side effects of subsequent evaluations shall have taken place"